# How to see what various control characters are as sent by my keyboard

Tags: unix, keyboard, ascii, hexdump, xxd

Usually I will use `xxd` to see what characters I type translate to in hex. For example:

```
$ xxd

hello
00000000: 0a68 656c 6c6f 0a                        .hello.
```

However, how would I do the same for:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

It seems when I enter either of these three it 'does something' outside the `xxd` program, rather than being recognized as a keyboard input for which I want to see the hex codes. So how can I see those values sent by my keyboard for all character combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the command line console, you can enter codes like <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> by first entering <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>.

So for example, if you type in the following:

> xxd <<<'<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>'

Then you should see the following output:

```
00000000: 010a                                     ..
```

(where, as I'm sure you realise, the `01` corresponds to `^A` and `0a` is the line break that comes after it)

On an ANSI terminal, you can enter [escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) in this way too. For example, type in this:

> echo '<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>[1;31mHello<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>[0m world'

to print one word in bright red and another in the default colour.

Comment: pretty neat! I got the first world bold on my terminal.